# How send a json to server

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I have a json that will be send to server in "Post".
There are parameters in json for 3 images to upload on server using multipart. I have no additional parameter to send it Multipart.

When I try it "PostMan" app of chrome to test it.

**Here are 2 cases-**

**case 1:-** select "raw" option in body & set content type "application json" in POSTMAN

Then all data had send to server expect images.

[image]

**Case 2:** Select "form-data" option in PostMan.

I have only to send some part of Json like images, certificates, venue, address, contact, achievement, level, at_home, certified, but unable to failed "coach_free_batch","coach_session" & "sports" section of json.

[image: for case 2]

**Please provide solution to upload all fields on server**

**Either idea to send "sports","coach_free_session"  in second case by Postman or any other idea**

**Json**

{"coach_free_batch":[{"sport_id":"10","batch_timing":{"end_time":"1:51 PM","start_time":"12:51 PM"},{"end_time":"11:51 AM","start_time":"10:51 AM"},{"end_time":"1:51 PM","start_time":"11:51 AM"}]},
{"sport_id":"4","batch_timing":[{"end_time":"1:52 PM","start_time":"12:52 PM"},
{"end_time":"3:52 PM","start_time":"2:52 PM"},{"end_time":"3:54 PM","start_time":"2:52 PM"}]}],
"coach_session":[{"timing":"2 Hour","rate":"24"},{"timing":"1 Hour","rate":"40"},
{"timing":"3 Hour","rate":"70"}],
"achievement":" national level",
"level":"Competitive","user_token":"XJnQCAz1ssuUCjgHtFs6","at_home":"1",
"sports":[{"user_sports_label_id":"7","sport_id":"2"},{"user_sports_label_id":"10","sport_id":"3"},
{"user_sports_label_id":"3","sport_id":"4"}],
"images":[{"image":"xxx"},
{"image":"xxx"}],
"experience":" more than 2 year","venue":"address","contact":"8236968542",
"certificates":[{"certificate":"certificate1"},{"certificate":"certifocate2"},{"certificate":"certificate3"}]}

**Method for send Data as raw**

```
public static String sendDataInJSONFormat(String url, String json) {
    
    // initialize
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null;
    String url1 = "";
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; application/json; charset=UTF-8;text/plain");

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        int timeoutSocket = 25000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8");
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to construct http requests in Java, or how to create the json payload from an object, or what?  I believe you are asking how to construct requests, so I would look into https://hc.apache.org/

Comment: I have successfully created the json but unable to send to send data with image.If I use MultipartEntity then what is key & its value format for sports section

Comment: how send "sports","coach_free_session","coach_session"  using Postman in second case. Is any suggestion